# Wpf - Resources lookup

Tags: wpf

I am wondering if controls look up into their own resources or in their parents one?

Lets say something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
 <Button someProp={StaticResource test1}>
  <Button.Resources>
   <local:something x:Key="test1"/>
  </Button.Resources>
 </Button>
<StackPanel>
```

Does Button look up in its own resources dictionary to find test1 or does it ask its parent (StackPanel) to find it?

I apologize in case this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the Framework will first look for `Resources` in the most local `Resources` collection, in this case, that of the `Button`. If nothing is found in there, it will continue looking up the control hierarchy, in this case, to the `StackPanel.Resources` section.

After this, it would look in the `UserControl.Resources` (if applicable) and then the `Window.Resources` and finally the `App.Resources` collection.

You can find out more from the [XAML Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) page at MSDN.